# Simple DB accessing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm using Java.
Instead of using

```
AmazonSimpleDB sdb = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(new PropertiesCredentials( 
                        new File("/AwsCredentials.properties")));
```

is there anyway to store the credential information (the accesskey and secretkey) in the program; something like

```
AmazonSimpleDB sdb = new AmazonSimpleDBClient("acesskey","secretkey");
```

It seems like this function does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at BasicAWSCredentials?

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretKey);

AmazonSimpleDB mDB = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
```

You can load accessKeyId and secretKey through the use of Properties.